# NullPointer from (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus")

Tags: android

Am using the below code

```
Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];
```

But,somehow I get a null pointer in the second line basicaly due to the fact that pdusObj  is null.I searched for resolving this but didnt get any positive results.Any link or explanation to resolve this will be very helpfull.

This is how am registering the service

```
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SMSReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

        // We want the alarm to go off 3 seconds from now.
        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        firstTime += 2000;// start 3 seconds after first register.

        // Schedule the alarm!
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime,300000, sender);// 5 min interval
```

Comment: How are you registering the Receiver, and for which actions? If this is an inner class, are you sure you're looking at the right Intent? Please post more of the surrounding code.

Comment: @MikeM. I have eddited my ques.This is not a inner class.

Comment: Ok, please explain what you're trying to do, because if you mean to be somehow receiving SMS, this setup isn't quite right.

Comment: Am trying to get an incomming message via a broadCast reciever.Also,I need to make sure that this service stays up all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `SMSReceiver` class is correct, you need to register it for the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action, instead of initiating a broadcast for it. If you want to monitor SMS only when your app is active, you would use the `registerReceiver()` method with the appropriate `IntentFilter`. If you want to monitor all incoming SMS, then your Receiver class needs to be statically registered in the manifest, again with the appropriate filter.

From your comment, it seems you'd want to register this in your manifest, which you would do like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I moved the registration part to be  handled in the manifest itself.The reason for the null pointer I suppose was due to bad registration of the broadcast reciver without any intent filter

Comment: Kind of. The framework handles the broadcast for incoming SMS, and attaches to it the extras that you're looking for. The reason you were getting an NPE is because the Intent you were explicitly broadcasting to the Receiver did not have those extras.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] pdusObj = new Object[] { (Object) bundle.get("pdus") };
```

This will create an array containing your object. `bundle.get("pdus")` will not return an Array of Objects but an Object.